# How to dynamically load partial view Via jquery ajax in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have page where i need input data and submit form. Page should dynamically load partialView through ajax. What i have:

SearchData Model:

```
public class SearchData
{
    public SearchData()
    {
        documents = GetDocuments();
        data = new List<DisplayData>();
    }
    public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
    public string emc { get; set; }
    public string receiver { get; set; }
    public DateTime receiveDateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime receiveDateTo { get; set; }
    public int document { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> documents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DisplayData> data { get; set; }
}
```

Above `DisplayData` is a model of my partial View `Show`.

My main `Index` view is below:

```
   @model web_archive_monitoring.Models.SearchData

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "View";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.emc)
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emc, new { @class = "form-control" })@*, @placeholder = "Password"*@
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>            
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.receiveDateFrom)
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @if (Model.isAdmin)
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.receiveDateFrom, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.receiveDateFrom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.receiveDateFrom, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.receiveDateTo)
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @if (Model.isAdmin)
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.receiveDateTo, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.receiveDateTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.receiveDateTo, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.receiver)
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.receiver, Model.receivers, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.receiver, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.document)
                        <br />
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.document, Model.documents, new { @id = "reg", @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.document, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>            
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="search">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("DisplayData", Model.data);
        }
    </div>
```

My partial View only display data that user queried.

```
@model IEnumerable<web_archive_monitoring.Models.DisplayData>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emc)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sendDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.docCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sendAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.receiveAmount)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.productCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.financePeriod)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.deliveryStatus)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.receiveDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.emcStatus)
        </th>
        @*<th></th>*@
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emc)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sendDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.docCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sendAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.receiveAmount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productCode)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.financePeriod)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.deliveryStatus)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.receiveDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.emcStatus)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>*@
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Here is my jquery call:

```
<script>
    var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Show")';
    $('form').submit(function () {        
        alert("debug1");
        var form = $(this).serialize();
        alert("data is: " + form);        
        $('#search').load(url, form);
        alert(url);
    })
</script>
```

And in the `DisplayData` controller i do some manipulation. query DB and return the same model with not empty `public IEnumerable<DisplayData> data` that uses my partialView.

```
public ActionResult DisplayData(SearchData model)
{
//some manipulation
model.data = data;
return PartialView("DisplayData", model);
}
```

But my partial View is not dynamically loaded. I will be glad for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assign Id `submit` to submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" class="btn btn-default"/>
```

Change your js as follows:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("DisplayData", "Show")';
$('#submit').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data:$('form').serialize(),
}).done(function (r) {
   $('#search').html(r);

}).fail(function (e) {
    console.log(e.responseText);
});
});
```

Change Controller code accordingly:

```
public ActionResult DisplayData(SearchData model)
{
//some manipulation
model.data = data;
return PartialView("DisplayData", model.data);
}
```

Comment: [InvalidOperationException]: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type &#39;web_archive_monitoring.Models.SearchData&#39;, but this dictionary requires a model item of type &#39;System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[web_archive_monitoring.Models.DisplayData]&#39;.

Comment: The problem is not in js. You are passing wrong model to the partial view. Currently your partial view requires IEnumerable<web_archive_monitoring.Models.DisplayData> but you are passing RegistrationData model to the view

Comment: Looking at it, it should be the 'SearchData' model you should be passing into the controller

Comment: I have updated the answer. As the form fields are binded to SearchData model therefore the receiving controller must also have SearchData object as parameter.

Comment: Ahmad, I edited names of models. So `RegistrationData` is `SearchData`

Comment: Add a breakpoint to the controller. See if its hitting. Also check the xhr response and tell me if it is working or need further enhancement

Comment: @Ahmad, Controller receives model. Get data from db succesfully. But noting else happens.

Comment: Errors on console or xhr response?

Comment: @Ahmad, GET http://localhost:62368/77e0690b0ca245d9ab13485047026ea3/browserLink net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Sorry I will not be able to answer this error. This occurs because of variety of reasons. Please debug the code in controller and in the view. See where error is occurring.

Comment: @Ahmad. I solve it. I should send `model.data` not `model` in controller return: `return PartialView("DisplayData", model.data);`. Thank You!

Comment: Pleasure it worked for you. I have updated my answer. Can you mark this as answer so that future visitors might see what actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add onclick method to your button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick=addPatient(); class="btn btn-default"/>
```

Change your js as follows:

```
function addPatient() {
   $('#search').load('/DisplayData');
}
```